# Opscenter installation help for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, opscenter

I have installed DSE 6(casssandra) on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Now i want to install the Opscenter. Tarball install is not working(may be I don't know the instructions for that).
So i tried this:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/install/doc/install/opscInstallDeb.html

I am stuck with this step:

```
echo "deb https://dDSA_profile_name:downloads_key@debian.datastax.com/enterprise \
stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/datastax.sources.list
```

Where is my downloads_key?

I have no idea how to go further from this?

Or if you can point me to the OpsCenter documentation in terms of the tarball install - that will be great too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 
it's not a programming question

Comment: Rather than closing could you please move it to the appropriate forum or at least suggest where it should be asked?

Comment: serverfault.com seems like the best bet

Comment: maybe https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a link to documentation handy, but it's talking about your datastax academy account password. You need to create a free account on https://academy.datastax.com/ in order to access the rpm/deb download servers.

They call it a download key because you have have the option, when logged into your academy account, to create a an authentication token just for downloads. Doing this can be handy:

1. If you are installing onto shared servers that you admin with others. Now you can set up deb/rpm repositories without sharing your academy password with all your colleagues.
2. If your password has special characters that require URL-escaping. Deb/rpm repos REQUIRE you to specify the username/password in the URL. Some characters aren't valid in urls and need to be url-escaped, which is possible if you know how but can be irritating. Download tokens only contain characters that are valid in urls, so are an easy way to work around this escaping problem. Typically the only warning you get that you have an escaping problem is that you get "401 not authorized" errors even when you've typed your password correctly. Make a token on academy.datastax.com if that's the case.